# How to implement a cache in Python that efficiently supports both dictionary and heap operations?

Tags: python, caching, data-structures

Is there a Python data structure that seamlessly combines a dictionary (with nested dictionaries or lists as values) and a heap, allowing sorting based on a specific value within the nested structures?

```py
cache = {"key1": {"time": time1, "info": "key1 info"}, "key2": {"time": time2, "info": "key2 info"}, ...}
```

or:

```py
cache = {"key1": [time1, "key1 info"], "key2": [time2, "key2 info"], ...}
```

here `time1`, `time2`, ... is the time of insertion or update of the entry.

The goal is to implement an efficient cache, checking key existence, validating the value's freshness (as it becomes outdated over time), and removing the oldest key when the cache is full. The dictionary should support heap operations either by using the nested key "time" or the zeroth element of the list.

Current options considered:

1. Forming a heap from the dictionary (drawback - expensive operation O(n^2)).
2. Implementing a class with separately stored heap and dictionary (drawback - complexity of synchronizing data in the heap and dictionary).
3. Simple iteration through the dictionary in O(n). This option is favored for its simplicity but might not be optimal.

Is there a more efficient solution or a different approach that avoids creating a custom data structure?

Comment: is the time part always the *current* time, or otherwise put: do insertions/updates of the dict elements always have *chronological* times? Or are there updates that "change history"?

Comment: @trincot ty for answer and question. time part is *always the current time* (time of insertion or update). But I didn't understand the part about *chronological* times. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean: could it ever occur that you add to the dict a time,info pair that is [5, "info1"] and then (later) add a pair that is [4, "info2"], so where the second time is less  than the first? I understand that this is not the case and the time values are never decreasing, but "chronological" (increasing timestamps).

Comment: I can't change history, of course

Comment: What exactly do you need from a heap? Python's `dict` is already insertion ordered, so it is no problem to get the oldest or newest item.

Comment: I'm writing up an answer right now...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ty!
1. I didn't know that since Python 3.7 LIFO order is guaranteed in popitem() dict's method
2. It seems that OrderedDict and its *popitem(last=False)* is what I need (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem)

Please don't stop if you're writing an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `dict` is already insertion ordered (on old versions, use `collections.OrderedDict`) similar to a time-sorted heap. This means the oldest inserted item is always at the front. Instead of updating values, remove-and-insert the item instead to force moving updated items to the back.

In order to use `dict` as a time-based cache, use the following approach. You can turn this into a separate subclass, provide helper functions, or add the code inline. A subclass is nicer and avoids misuses but involves many special methods, so I will show the simpler helper functions and assume a Time To Live (`ttl`) is given.

- Items should be of the form `"key": (time, value)`. It is advantageous to have immutable values (i.e. a `tuple` or `NamedTuple`) to prevent invalidating the constraint of a valid `time`.
- On insertion, remove any previous items of the same key. This forces the item to be inserted at the last position.

  ```
  def set(cache, key, value):
       cache.pop(key, None)  # clear the previous position if any
       cache[key] = (time.monotonic(), value))
  ```
- On access, simply check the time. You likely want to directly evict outdated keys on access for efficiency.

  ```
  def get(cache, key):
       key_time, value = cache[key]
       if key_time < time.monotonic() + ttl:  # check timestamp validity
           del cache[key]
           raise KeyError(key)
       return value
  ```
- To evict the oldest item, simply fetch the first key and remove this.

  ```
  def free(cache):
       if cache:
          oldest_key = next(iter(cache))
          del cache[oldest_key]
  ```
- To evict all outdated items, simply iterate until the first key that is still valid.

  ```
  def clean(cache):
       outdated, deadline = [], time.monotonic() + ttl
       for key, (key_time, _) in cache.items():
           if key_time < deadline:
               outdated.append(key)
           else:  # all following keys are valid as well
               break
       for key in outdated:
           del cache[key]
  ```